# What is the different for UseGetSomeQuery Arg Value

Tags: redux, next.js, rtk-query

I'm new for the RTK Query for redux.

What's the different for auto generated hook in below two ways.

The first way look like correct from the docs but it return 304 network status.

Second way, return 200. working perfectly

1.

```
const ProjectsList = () => {
  const {
    data: projects,
    isLoading,
    isSuccess,
    isError,
    error,
  } = useGetProjectsQuery("projectList") // -- return 304 network status
}
```

2. worked fine. but cannot retrieve the object from the store. return.

```
const {
    data: projects,
    isLoading,
    isSuccess,
    isError,
    error,
  } = useGetProjectsQuery() // -- return 200 network status
```

Third, the memoized return uninitialize. It seem didn't correct.

// ApiSlice status return uninitialize

```
import { createSelector, createEntityAdapter } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
import { apiSlice } from "@/app/api/apiSlice"

const projectsAdapter = createEntityAdapter({})

export const projectsApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getProjects: builder.query({
      query: () => "/api/projects",
      validateStatus: (response, result) => {
        return response.status === 200 && !result.isError
      },
      transformResponse: (responseData) => {
        const loadedProjects = responseData.map((project) => {
          project.id = project._id
          return project
        })

        return projectsAdapter.setAll(initialState, loadedProjects)
      },
      providesTags: (result, error, arg) => {
        if (result?.ids) {
          return [
            { type: "Project", id: "LIST" },
            ...result.ids.map((id) => ({ type: "Project", id })),
          ]
        } else return [{ type: "Project", id: "LIST" }]
      },
    }),
  }),
})

export const {
  useGetProjectsQuery,
} = projectsApiSlice

export const selectProjectsResult =
  projectsApiSlice.endpoints.getProjects.select()

// creates memoized selector
const selectProjectsData = createSelector(
  selectProjectsResult,
  (projectsResult) => {
    console.log("projectsResult: ", projectsResult) // -> { isUninitialized: true, status: "uninitialize" }
    return projectsResult.data
  }
)

export const { 
  selectAll: selectAllProjects,
  selectById: selectProjectById,
  selectIds: selectProjectIds,
} = projectsAdapter.getSelectors(
  (state) => selectProjectsData(state) ?? initialState
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your `query` function is just `query: () => "/api/projects"` (so, not using the argument in any way), both will make exactly the same request for the same resource.
There is no difference between them and every difference you see is probably something random happening on the server and not bound to either invocation.

As for **retrieving from the store**, there is a difference however.
Your code

```js
export const selectProjectsResult =
  projectsApiSlice.endpoints.getProjects.select()
```

creates a selector for the cache entry that is created calling `useGetProjectsQuery()` - if you wanted the cache entry for `useGetProjectsQuery("foo")`, that would need to be `projectsApiSlice.endpoints.getProjects.select("foo")`.

Please note that there should almost never be any reason to use those selectors with React components - those are an escape hatch if you are not working with React. If you are working with React, use the `useGetProjectsQuery` hook with `selectFromResult`.

I am seeing people use `select` in this fashion quite often recently and I assume this traces back to a tutorial that misunderstood the feature - did you learn that in a tutorial and could you share that tutorial? Maybe I can convince the author to change that part.

Comment: Thanks sharing your solution. The author create a tag in video 16:20.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9YnZHQsWmJs&list=PL0Zuz27SZ-6P4dQUsoDatjEGpmBpcOW8V&index=10

Comment: Ugh. Yeah, that's not a "tag" or "label". That should be data. He essenitally just forces you to make more requests.

Comment: I was more talking about creating a selector with `select()` or `select(arg)` though - you should not have any need for that at all if you are only using React components.

Comment: Thanks phry. Which way we able to check it make more request? From the network tab?

Comment: Yes, you would see requests happening in the browser network tab.